# min() in python: stop searching after certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I am trying to find the minimum of three values which are provided by three functions. What I've done so far looks something like this:

```
value = min(function1(), function2(), function3())
```

The functions are recursive and need quite some time to process. However, the smallest output possible is always 0. Which is why I'd like to know if there is a build-in function where I can specify a certain value after which min() will stop searching. Surely I could write my own min-function but maybe there's another way?

Comment: Are your functions generators?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Could they be? I just tried this with the functions being generators and as expected got `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'generator' and 'generator'`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: you'd have to chain them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not what their current code is doing, though.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: no, I was indeed making the wrong assumption that the functions each produced a sequence. Clearly, they do not.

Comment: @Lou Do you just have three function calls hardcoded like that, or do you have a list with functions of unknown size?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a generator function that stops yielding if `0` has been seen, or some other condition is met:

```
def takeuntil(predicate, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        yield x
        if predicate(x):
            return
```

This is modelled on the [`itertools.takewhile()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), but yields that last value that matched the predicate.

Combined with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) you can then take the minimum value of the output, and anything beyond `0` is ignored:

```
values = (f() for f in (function1, function2, function3))
result = min(takeuntil(lambda x: x == 0, values))
```

I used a generator expression to call each function in series, that way you don't even call later functions if one of the first functions produces `0`.

Demo:

```
>>> def function1():
...     print('Function 1 called')
...     return 42
...
>>> def function2():
...     print('Function 2 called')
...     return 0
...
>>> def function3():
...     print('Function 3 called')
...     return 18
...
>>> values = (f() for f in (function1, function2, function3))
>>> min(takeuntil(lambda x: x == 0, values))
Function 1 called
Function 2 called
0
```

`function3` is never called because `function2()` produced `0`.

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!